# Is this the right way to save the Java object through JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How do i save this MonthlyGcsBillPaymentL java object passed as a parameter. When i run this, it does nothing and it does not even throw an error

```
 @Query(value = "insert into MonthlyGcsBillPaymentL(MONTHLYBILL_PAYMENT_ID,GCS_SEQUENCENO," +
            "BILLING_CYCLEID," +
            "GCS_ACCOUNT_ID," +
            "BILL_DUE_DATE," +
            "MONTHLY_BILL_AMOUNT," +
            "BILL_PAID_DATE," +
            "INACTIVITY_FEE," +
            "COLLECTOR_STATUS," +
            "COLLECTOR_STARTDATE," +
            "GCS_SERVICE_FEE," +
            "BANK_SERVICE_FEE) "
            + "VALUES (:#{#obj.monthlybillPaymentId},:#{#obj.gcsSequenceno},:#{#obj.billingCycleid},:#{#obj.gcsAccountId}, " +
            " :#{#obj.billDueDate}, :#{#obj.monthlyBillAmount}, :#{#obj.billPaidDate},:#{#obj.inactivityFee}, :#{#obj.collectorStatus},  :#{#obj.collectorStartdate} , :#{#obj.gcsServiceFee}, :#{#obj.bankServiceFee} )", nativeQuery = true)
    public void saveMonthlyBillPaymentCollectorInfo(@Param("obj") MonthlyGcsBillPaymentL obj) {
    }
```

Comment: You are using Spring Data JPA. Ditch this method and just call the `save` method.

Comment: Can you clarify how to call save?